# Record type profile and page layout setting

Tags: administration, profile, page-layout, record-type

I created a new record type and during the process I added it to profiles and assigned the new record type page layout. This was done in DEV.

When I move the record type from DEV to FUll sandbox using change set , I do not see the record type appear for my profile or neither the new record type page layout is present. I had to go to my profile and add the record type manually and set the page layout in page layout assignment.

Is there a way I can do this using change set? or do I have to manually set the page layout and profile for the new record type every time I move from one org to another org?

Comment: Did you include the affected Profile in the Change Set?

Comment: No I did not include it in the change set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Sets will only make changes to Profiles if that Profile is included as part of the Change Set in the "Profile Settings" section. Likewise, if a Profile is included in the Change Set, deployment will only change the target Profile settings if the related components are included.

If you make a change set with the Record Type, the Page Layout, and the Profile all included, it should deploy and make the Profile association automatically. I say "should", because it doesn't seem to work right all the time, and I would always double-check after deployment anyway.

Incidentally, this also goes for deploying custom objects and fields, among other things. If you do not include Profiles when deploying new fields, the default access of "No Access" will be applied when deployed.